# Where can I find the infrared band positions for phosphorus compounds?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, spectroscopy

I am trying to interpret an IR spectrum where I have $\ce{(NPCl2)3}$

I have $\ce{P-N}$, $\ce{P=N}$ and $\ce{P-Cl}$ bonds and it is cyclic.

Where can I find or does anyone know what the general ranges for these stretches are?

I found a website that told me $\ce{P=N}$ is around $1170 \, \mathrm{cm}^{-1}$.

Comment: Have you checked the National Institute of Standards and Technology Atomic Spectra Database? http://www.nist.gov/pml/data/asd.cfm They also have a Handbook of Basic Atomic Spectroscopic Data which you may find useful: http://physics.nist.gov/PhysRefData/Handbook/Tables/phosphorustable2.htm

Answer (score 2):

A good resource for IR and Raman bands is ["Infrared and Raman Characteristic Group Frequencies: Tables and Charts" by George Socrates](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470093072). There you can find a chart containing the positions and intensities of bands observed in the infrared spectra of phosphorus compounds (explanation: "w", "m", "s"  specify the observed intensity of the bands means whereby "w" stands for "weak", "m" for "medium", and "s" for "strong"; additionally the prefix "v" can be given meaning "very", e.g. "vs" means "very strong"):

[image]

[image]

More specifically you find the following numbers for the different bands you are looking for:

[image]

[image]

There is also another comment on $\ce{P-Cl}$ bands:

> Compounds containing the $\ce{P-Cl}$ bond have a medium-to-strong absorption
>   at $605 - 435$ $\mathrm{cm}^{-1}$ due to the $\ce{P-Cl}$ stretching vibration.
>   The position of the band due to the $\ce{P-X}$ ($\ce{X}$=$\ce{F}$ or $\ce{Cl}$) stretching vibration is affected by the oxidation state of the phosphorus atom. 'In the presence of
>   more than one halogen atom directly attached to the phosphorus atom, two
>   peaks are observed due to the asymmetric and symmetric stretching vibrations
>   respectively. Difluorides of the type $\ce{-P(O)F2}$ absorb at $930-895$ $\mathrm{cm}^{-1}$ and $890-870$ $\mathrm{cm}^{-1}$